# Creating Outlook rule acting on sent email flagged for action

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

Is there a way to create an auto-rule in Outlook to save a copy of emails I sent out in a particular folder if I flag the email for action (my own action, not recipient's)? I can create rule for flagged incoming emails, but can't seem to find out how (or if it's possible) to create one for flagged outgoing emails.

Comment: **Messages sent to a public folder to a group to a folder** doesn't work for you ?

Comment: Not really. It requires me to define assign a value of the person/group I send to. The only thing to trigger the rule is the flag, and it applies to any email sent to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "flagged for action" condition is not supported for outgoing rules. The possible workaround is to use other markers available, like categories, importance/sensitivity or tags in subjects or message bodies.

Comment: OK thanks, for confirming my suspicion. All can't be used except categories, which unfortunately take more clicks then I want. I guess another question coming up soon on creating a shortcut button to assign category when composing email.